# add custome template in sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, templates

I have a dotnet implemented site. I want to create same site template in sharepoint. what i have to do. Please if possible tell me detail steps.  waiting for reply......its too urgent

Answer (score 2):

Custom Site Template is a big subject on SharePoint . While there is no out of the box way to convert an ASP.NET Site to the SharePoint Custom Site Template.

Steps to do is to dissect the ASP.NET Site to various parts.

1. User Controls
2. CSS & JavaScripts
3. Pages
4. Custom dlls

Change each of the Parts to Web Parts / Drop the Control in the Control Templates folder.Create a new web part page for the page / Page Layout & Master Pages deployed as the Features.